# Ограничить таблицу по размеру или по количеству строк postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Хочется в postgresql сделать что-то аналогичное [capped-collection MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/). Ограничить размер таблички, а новые данные писать на месте старых.

Или вариант правильно оформить партицирование и удалять старые таблицы целиком переодически. Как это лучше оформить?

Нужна перезапись по кругу, но чтоб не было мусора. Автовакуум на этих данных дело гиблое. Поэтому метод с primary key и остатком от деления не подойдет т.к. будет создавать мусор.

Строки все фиксированной длинны.

Comment: может просто ежедневное задание, удаляющее на определенную глубину по дате ? Как вариант конечно можно сделать триггер на insert записи, который при этом будет удалять запись с минимальным id, если записей более определенного кол-ва, правда если select count() долгий, то я бы такой триггер вешал когда таблица уже наполнена и считать кол-во записей не надо

Comment: От удаления хочу уйти куда подальше. удаление делает мусор, а потом вакуум будет проходить по всей таблице а не по её началу. а 100 гигов на посредственном железе...

Comment: Что вы называете мусором ? удаление позволит поддерживать объем на боле менее стабильном уровне. Хотя теоретически может потребоваться реорганизация индексов, это конечно очень дорогая операция, особенно на 100гб.

Comment: От "Мусора" Вам никуда не деться. Потому как update в postgres ни что иное как delete и insert, потому как MVCC. Посмотрите в сторону партиционирования, каждая партиция, например один день. И делайте транкей ненужной партиции.
Тем более что вакуум это не только удаление старых версий строк, но и сбор статистики для планировщика. По этому, без него никак

Comment: @sfalkon там не будет update. нет удалений - нет мусора.

Comment: @Mike 100-200 гигов планируемый объем.. потому и спрашиваю

Comment: А как планируете писать новые данные на место старых? Postgresql использует версионирование, он в принципе так не может.
Какая планируема будет нагрузка на базу, сколько транзакций в секунду, что вы так боитесь вакуума?

Comment: @sfalkon  я не боюсь вакуума. ему там просто нечего делать если спланируем правильно. Собираем статистику и храним пока она актуальна. 30 гигов в месяц записями по 12 столбцов с циферками.
закинул бы это в монго или в rrdb какую-нибудь, но агрегация со сложным запросом работает жуть как медленно.

Задача борьбы с вакуумом - это задача влезть на слабое железо. Выдавать результат за приемлемое время на АМД-А4 и целероне.

Answer (score 0):

Откровенно говоря, 30 гигов в месяц ни ахти какая нагрузка.
Ну тогда, при таком раскладе, пишите все в разные таблицы и truncate вам в помощь. После него вакуум не прейдет.
Оттащите, как в мурзилках пишут, wal'ы на отдельный диск, растяните checkpoint'ты, в общем снижайте нагрузку на дисковую подсистему.

Но смущает как на таком железе собираетесь сложные запросы переваривать, и видится мне что вакуум тут не самое страшное. В общем памяти по больше и если будете много аналитики и тяжелых запросов, добавите реплики, что бы разделить запросы.

Comment: дело не в вакууме, а в том как сделать перезаписываемые по кругу таблицы. чтоб руками туда не лезть раз в месяц делать truncate

Comment: wal`ов на эту табличку тоже не будет.

Comment: а как вы собираетесь отключить wal? unlogged табличка ака сделай truncate всей таблицы при любом рестарте?

Comment: @eri то что вы хотите невозможно, это противоречит принципам мультиверсионности и конкурентного доступа. wal отключить нельзя, можно задать минимальный уровень детализации.

Так же вы должны понимать, что без wal, в случае сбоя, вы потеряете все данные. Настраивайте различные задержки, что бы растягивать запись на диск. Но это требует памяти и побольше

Comment: И ещё, если вакуум не будет бродить по вашим таблицам, у вас не будет статистики для планировщика, а это, как минимум, не оптимальные запросы. И да, автовакуум не отключается, он всеравно будет

Comment: @Мелкий именно.

Comment: @sfalkon задерживаться данные будут во фронтэнде. там они меньше занимают места(без индекса и метаданных). Сбрасываю их через copy in в табличку и пусть ложаться прямо на диск без задержки.

Comment: @sfalkon задерживаться данные будут во фронтэнде. там они меньше занимают места(без индекса и метаданных). Сбрасываю их через copy in в табличку и пусть ложаться прямо на диск без задержки.

Comment: Так если вам один фиг не нужны данные - то зачем их писать в базу вообще?

Comment: @Мелкий чтоб аналитику по ним сделать пока они ещё там

Comment: Вы сами себе противоречите, если данные будут задерживаться на фронтэнде, как писалось выше, то о какой аналитике идет речь на стороне базы? И вообще, зачем морочиться с базой данных, если не планируется использовать её функционал? PostgreSQL не даст вам того, чего вы хотите, у него другие задачи.

В таком виде пользоваться базой, проще в файлы писать, быстрее будет работать на крайний случай KV-хранилище.

Comment: Сбросил раз в 5 минут пару десятков тыщ строк, раз в час аналитика.. ничего не противоречу.

У постгреса быстро отрабатываются пересечения интервалов времени. больше от него ничего не требуется. монго их мусолит по 10-20 минут 100% проца..